# How do i print the time to this format 23:44:22.184320

Tags: go

How do i print the time to this format?

```
23:44:22.184320
```

What I have tried is

```
func main() {
   // Which will print to the current time
   fmt.Println(time.Now())

   // How do I convert to
   // 23:44:22.184320
}
```

I have checked this link but I couldn't figure out how to do so https://gobyexample.com/time-formatting-parsing

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
time.Now().Format("15:04:05.999999")
```

Note that the time layout for the `time` package is:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
```

[time package](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

Comment: I believe that's microseconds, and that is already given by the `.999999`. You can further go to nanoseconds if you need the extra precision e.g. `15:04:05.999999999`

Comment: You can use `Time.Nanosecond()` to derive the microseconds e.g. `float64(time.Now().Nanosecond()) / 1000`